# How to find the probability that both numbers selected are odd, given that their sum is even

Tags: probability

Thirty-five cards numbered from 1 through 35 are placed into a box, and two cards are selected without replacement. Find the probability that both numbers selected are odd, given that their sum is even.

For this question, I got 1190 total combinations, out of which would 306 would be both odds. So the probability of getting odd would be 306/1190. In the same way, I calculated the probability of being sum even. I use the formula P(both odd|sum even)=P(both odd and sum even)/p(sum even). I'm confused is the probability of being both odd and being sum even the same? And how to find the probability of being both odd and sum even? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question to show your work.

Answer (score 1):

The only way for the sum to be even is for both selected numbers to have the same parity (both odd or both even).

There are $\binom{18}{2}=17 \cdot 9$ pairs of odd numbers when selecting without replacement.  (I've assumed that the order in which you select your numbers doesn't matter, but since the resulting factor of $2$ appears in both the numerator and denominator of the fraction you'll eventually reach, this assumption doesn't matter.)  There are $\binom{17}{2}=17 \cdot 8$ pairs of even numbers when selection without replacement.

Each of these combinations is equally likely, so the probability that you've selected a pair of odd numbers is $$\frac{17 \cdot 9}{17 \cdot 9 + 17 \cdot 8}=\frac{9}{17}.$$

Comment: Thank you, Robert! I wanted to make sure I was correct. I got the same answer. I got 306 combinations of both odds and 272 combinations of both even. So, total combinations that add to even is 306+272= 578 because either odd and odd or even and even sum up to even. The probability is total outcomes of odd combinations/ outcomes of sum even= 306/578=9/17.

Comment: @NepaliKeto Glad I could help.  Upvotes and acceptances of answers you find useful are always appreciated.

Comment: What would happen if it allowed replacement? Can you please give me a little hint? Thank you.

Comment: @NepaliKeto Then there would be $18^2$ ways to draw two odd numbers and $18^2+17^2$ ways to draw two numbers with an even sum.  The total number of possible draws would be $35^2$, but that number never factors into the calculation.